# RDB to JSON in Kettle?

Tags: json, etl, pentaho, kettle

I'm currently trying to get a handle on how Kettle 4.4 handles data transformations by trying to port something I'm currently doing via Python  to a Kettle job.

I have a relational database with four tables that I need to import into my data pipeline.  Here's a simplified version of the model...

#### Widgets

```
+-----------+-------------+----------------+
| WIDGET_ID |    Name     |     Notes      |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+
|         1 | Gizmo       | Red paint job  |
|         2 | Large Gizmo | Blue paint job |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+
```

#### Customers

```
+-----------+------------+----------------------------------+
| WIDGET_ID |    Name    |         Mailing_Address          |
+-----------+------------+----------------------------------+
|         1 | Acme, Inc. | 123 Fake Street, Springfield, IL |
|         2 | Fake Corp. | 555 Main Street, Small Town, IN  |
|         2 | Acme, Inc. | 123 Fake Street, Springfield, IL |
+-----------+------------+----------------------------------+
```

#### Inventory

```
+-----------+--------+------------+
| WIDGET_ID | Amount |    Date    |
+-----------+--------+------------+
|         2 |  11000 | 2012-01-15 |
|         1 |  13000 | 2012-02-05 |
|         1 |    900 | 2013-01-01 |
+-----------+--------+------------+
```

I'd like to be able to take the above and produce JSON output like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "Gizmo",
    "Notes": "Red Paint Job",
    "Customers": [
        {
            "Name": "Acme, Inc.",
            "Address": "123 Fake Street..."
        }
    ],
    "Inventory": [
        {
            "Amount": 13000,
            "Date": "2012-02-05"
        },
        {
            "Amount": 900,
            "Date": "2013-01-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

My attempts to use Kettle's joins, JS transforms and JSON output have not been very successful, and I find the documentation to be quite lacking. Can anyone help me out, or point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use 3 (well  6 in total) kettle steps for this transformation:

1) add 3 **table input steps** one for each table.

2) add next a  **Multiway Merge Join** step, group the 3 table input step arrow flows onto this,
choose widget_id as key field, choose inner join type.

3) add 1 **json ouput step** to the output flow the multiway  join step.

to make the final json format you have to use the JSONPath notation:

http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

hope it helps.

(if you are new in kettle i recommend to go trough the samples folder included in kettle spoon)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Would I have to do the JsonPath transformations outside of Kettle, or is it something that I can accomplish within the designer?

Comment: click on the json output step, and there you can edit your fields with jsonpath notation.  (no need to go outside spoon design mode)